# Can I measure the performance of a webworker using Chrome dev tools?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I have a project where a lot of the total computation time is spent inside workers - the main thread just waits until a bunch of workers are finished. But I want to see which part of my code is slowing everything down the most.

So logically I use dev tools to measure the performance:

[image]

Sorry for the bad quality, but notice that I measured the performance for 11000ms seconds but only a self time of about 6500ms is shown. So there is about 4500ms which I can't see.

Usually I use this tool to figure out which part of my code I should improve to refine the process, as it shows the *ms* taken line by line

**Is there any way I can view the performance of web workers?**

Comment: try adding `performance.now()` to a `console.log()`?

Comment: You can view in scripts the workers you have and from there open dev console for that worker

Comment: @juvian how does one do that?

Comment: Try https://umaar.com/dev-tips/89-debug-per-thread/

Comment: @juvian I tried what is told in that link, but it doesn't allow me to see the performance

Comment: @ThomasW searched a lot on the web and couldn´t find anything, but after playing around with dev console finally found the option, just run the profiler normally and then view thread instead of main : https://snag.gy/gPHvoy.jpg

Comment: @juvian thanks! That doesn't show me inline time measurements, but please post it as an answer!

Answer (score 7):

While the best way of meassuring the worker job is to profile the job without worker, you might miss things such as time spent on transfers and messages with main threads. After some time playing around with chrome dev console, ended up finding that in profiler you can view in timeline below main thread the worker thread execution, and in call tree you can change from main to DedicatedWorker thread :

[image]

Comment: This dropdown menu is no longer there in latest Chrome? https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-frontend/issues/47#issuecomment-492550898 **Edit**: OHH, you can just click the thread in the timeline and it loads the data into the bottom-up/call-tree panel for that thread.

Comment: @Joe Good to know ^^

Comment: Trying to find this in 2021... in the timeline you need to collapse the "Main" entry and then you can see your workers.  Expanding a worker sets it active in the lower panel.